# Calculate probabilities from Probit Model - R Command?

Tags: r, probability, glm

I'm working with a Probit model, and would like to calculate the probabilities from my model for each observation in my DF. I know I can calculate this using the formula, however I am wondering if there is a quick way to output the probabilities and append them to my DF.

I am running the following model:

```
attach(non.part.2)
y <- cbind(E)
x1 <- cbind(tech.ems, med.com, tech.nonemerg)
probit <- glm(y ~ x1, family = binomial (link = "probit"))
summary(probit)
```

I am running several models, so it would be nice to be able to have R spit out the probabilities and allow me to name them in my DF(non.part.2) - something like p_x1 - so that I can run summary stats on the various models later.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's not yet reproducible by virtue of no data, but generally `predict( ..., type="response")` should deliver useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
non.part2$p_x1 <- predict(probit, yourDataToPredictOn, type = "response")
```